# Popup alert not showing when a match is not found in database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using this function to check to see if a certain handle exists in my database. It works fine for the most part - if the handle exists, it updates the table view to display that user. However if there is no match for the handle entered, my alert view is not showing up.

```
// Search DB for matching handles
@IBAction func searchHandleButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {

    if let handleToSearch = handleSearchTextField.text?.lowercased() {
        let databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        databaseRef.child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "lowercaseHandle").queryEqual(toValue: handleToSearch).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let snapDict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject] {

                for each in snapDict{

                    let key  = each.key
                    let handle = each.value["handle"] as! String
                    self.returnedHandles.removeAll()
                    self.returnedHandles.append(handle)
                    let pic = each.value["profilePicture"] as! String
                    self.returnedUsersProfilePic = pic
                    self.returnedUsersUID = key

                    if handle.lowercased() != handleToSearch {
                        self.noHandleFoundAlert()
                    }

                    if handle != "" {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.getFriendsInfo()
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, withCancel: {(Err) in
            //                print(Err.localizedDescription)
        })
    }
}
```

I put the alert in the loop as:

```
if handle.lowercased() != handleToSearch {
      self.noHandleFoundAlert()
}
```

But obviously this isn't the correct approach as it isn't working. If I enter a random string of characters, or a handle that I know isn't in use, the alert doesn't come up. Where else would I put the alert so it will show up if there's no match?

Comment: Before converting the `snapshot.value` to a `Dictionary`, check if it exists with `snapshot.exists()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-exists

Comment: Great, this fixed it. I just put everything from `if let snapDict` down inside an `if snapshot.exists()` condition, with the `else` being the `noHandleFoundAlert`. Thanks, and feel free to post it as an answer if you want the karma!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The snapshot will be converted to an empty dictionary with your current code.

Before converting the snapshot.value to a Dictionary, check if it exists with `snapshot.exists()`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDataSnapshot#-exists

Answer (score 0):

You first have to check if the query you made, has data. So you have a

```
 .hasChild("handle")
```

it returns a boolean, so when is true you do the loop, else notified user.